# Selecionar todos os ítens da árvore Treeview

Tags: delphi, treeview

tenho a seguinte árvore abaixo:
[image: Árvore Treeview]

Preciso fazer com que, ao clicar em "Todos", o mesmo selecione todos os nós e seus sub-nós da árvore. Já tentei vários laços usando a propriedade "Selected" dos nós com a propriedade "MultiSelect" marcada para "True", mas mesmo assim ele seleciona apenas o último nó. Eu preciso que seja selecionado todos. Abaixo, segue o código da função chamado ao clicar no botão "Todos":

```
procedure TForm1.SelecionaTodos;
var
  x:Integer;
begin
  for x := 0 to tv1.Items.Count - 1 do
    tv1.Items[x].Selected :=  True;
end;
```

Dado o exposto acima, alguém aqui sabe me dar algum exemplo, ou um local que tenho um exemplo claro do que preciso?

Comment: Boas-vindas. Para continuarmos dentro da [finalidade do site](/help) é importante você [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código fornecido por um [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. **Nota:** [NÃO usar imagens para códigos e logs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.